# Set color of Radar Graph markers

Tags: javascript, node.js, plotly

I have created the following radar chart using this code. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/dshaikh/pen/NWqRqQX?editable=true)

```
data = [{
  type: 'scatterpolar',
  r: [39, 28, 8, 7, 28, 39],
  theta: ['A','B','C', 'D', 'E', 'A'],
  fill: 'toself'
}]

layout = {
  polar: {
    radialaxis: {
      visible: true,
      range: [0, 50]
    }
  },
  showlegend: false
}

Plotly.newPlot("myDiv", data, layout)
```

Which results in this:
[image]
How can I set the color of each of the dots shaping the polygon?

With this tool, [online graph maker](https://chart-studio.plot.ly/create/#/),  it seems you can set the colors on a scale, but I would like to set each on of the dots separately,

Any direction to how to customize the rest of the elements will be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
#myDiv path.point{
  fill: blue !important;
}
```

And if you want to further customize the colors you can use CSS :nth-of-type(n) modifier https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp

```js
data = [{
  type: 'scatterpolar',
  r: [37, 28, 8, 7, 28, 39],
  theta: ['A','B','C', 'D', 'E', 'A'],
  fill: 'toself',
  marker : { color : '#B80102'}
}]


layout = {
  polar: {
    radialaxis: {
      visible: true,
      range: [0, 50]
    }
  },
  showlegend: false
}

Plotly.newPlot("myDiv", data, layout)
```

```css
#myDiv path.point{
  fill: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <!-- Load plotly.js into the DOM -->
 <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id='myDiv'><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yeah, look into :nth-of-type https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp for that, as I said. You can use #myDiv path.point:nth-of-type(1){fill:red !important;} and #myDiv path.point:nth-of-type(7){fill:purple !important;}  for example.

Comment: Im using this on nodejs, so there's no DOM

Answer (score 0):

There are ton of possible configurations, and exploring you can get a an idea of any possible setup you might think of. Plotly is truly amazing.

For the configuration I was trying to do this is the configuration:
You can try it on the [codepen](https://codepen.io/dshaikh/pen/NWqRqQX?editable=true)

```
data = [{
  type: 'scatterpolar',
  mode : "markers+lines",

  line : {
    color   :   "rgb(158, 27, 66)",
    width   :   "2",
    dash    :   "solid",
   shape    :   "linear"
 },
 r: [5, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2],
    theta: ['Tecnologia','Innovacion','Optimismo Digital', 'Transformador', 'Atracc. y desarrollo de talento', 'Referente', 'Etica y honestidad',
            'Personas', 'Aprendizaje Continuo','Promocion del aprendizaje', 'Emprendedor', 'Escucha', 'Comunica y comparte', 'Mejora continua', 
            'Base tecnica y rigor', 'Logro', 'Crecimiento rentable' ],
 fill: 'toself',
 fillcolor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)',
 marker : { color : [8, 8, 8, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3 ],
        colorscale : [
          [0, '#38C041'],  [0.125, '#DDD01B'],  [0.25, '#c7e9b4'],  [0.375, '#7fcdbb'],  [0.5, '#41b6c4'],  [0.625, '#1d91c0'],  [0.75, '#225ea8'],  [0.875, '#253494'],[1, '#081d58']
        ],
                size    :   10
              }

 }]

 layout = {
    polar: {
    radialaxis: {
    visible: true,
    range: [0, 7]
    }
 },
   showlegend: false,
   width: 800,
   height: 700,
   margin:{
      l :   0,
      r :   0,
      t :   100,
      b :   0,
      pad   :   0,
      autoexpand    :       true
   }


 }
```